# Mostrar ubicación con nombre, no coordenadas

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Tengo una aplicación que abre un Maps y con 2 botones hace que se mueva a mi ubicación actual y que lo guarde.

Pero sólo sé hacer que salgan las coordenadas (longitud y latitud). ¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer que muestre el nombre de la Ciudad, o Calle, o algo?

Dejo mi código por aquí:

```
package com.example.dam.proyectocristian.Mapas;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String UBICACION_KEY = "ubicacion_key";

    //Nuestro mapa
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //Para guardar la Longitud i la Latitud
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    //Botones para ver nuestra posicion y guardar nuestra posicion
    private ImageButton buttonSave;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    String ubi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        //Obtener el SupportMapFragment y notificarnos cuando el mapa este listo.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Inicializamos googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Inicializamos views y onclick listeners
        buttonSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Para saber nuestra Localizacion
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creando un location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Obtenemos la Longitut/Latitud
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            moveMap();
        }
    }

    //Funcion para mover el mapa
    private void moveMap() {
        //String para mostrar la Latitud y Longitud
        String msg ="Latitud: "+latitude+" Longitud: "+longitude;
        ubi = msg;

        //Usamos un LatLng Object para guardar las Coordenadas
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Añadimos un marker para el mapa
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //Posicion
                .draggable(true) //Para que se pueda mover
                .title("Esta es tu ubicacion"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Limpiamos las marcas
        mMap.clear();

        //Añadimos una nueva marca con un click largo.
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        moveMap();
    }


    //Funcion para Mover el mapa a tu ubicacion o Para pasar nuestra Ubicacion con un String a la Actividad MenuAvisos.
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v == buttonCurrent)
        {
            getCurrentLocation();
            moveMap();
        }
        if (v == buttonSave)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(UBICACION_KEY, ubi.toString());
            setResult(MenuAvisos.RESULT_OK, intent);

            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí hay dos opciones, una es que tu tengas previamente almacenados los datos en un objeto donde se contenga latitud, longitud, además de las descripciones de la ciudad, calle, etc

La segunda opción es usar la [API Places](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start) que tiene atributos como :

- getName(): el nombre del sitio.
- getAddress(): la dirección del sitio, en formato de lenguaje natural.
- getID(): el identificador textual del sitio. Obtén más información sobre los id. de sitio en el resto de esta página.
- getPhoneNumber(): el número de teléfono del sitio.
- getWebsiteUri(): el URI del sitio web del sitio, en caso de ser conocido.     Este es el sitio web que mantienen el negocio u otra entidad relacionada con el sitio. El resultado es nulo si no existe ningún sitio web conocido.
- getLatLng(): la ubicación geográfica del
  sitio, especificada en coordenadas de latitud y longitud.
- getViewport(): un viewport, que se devuelve como un objeto
  LatLngBounds y sirve para mostrar el sitio en el mapa. El resultado
  puede ser nulo si el tamaño del sitio no es conocido.
- getLocale(): la configuración regional para la cual están localizadas el nombre y la
  dirección.
- getPlaceTypes(): una lista de tipos de sitios que caracterizan este sitio en particular. Para acceder a una lista de
  los tipos de sitios disponibles, consulta la documentación de la
  interfaz de Place.
- getPriceLevel(): el nivel de precio de este sitio,
  devuelto como valor entero que varía de 0 (el más económico) a 4 (el
  más costoso).
- getRating(): una calificación agregada del sitio, que
  se devuelve como un flotante con valores que varían de 1,0 a 5,0,
  según las reseñas agregadas del usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el [**código de ejemplo**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Route-Google-Maps) de la imagen.

[Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) puede ser una opción aunque no tan completa como PLaces API.

Comment: Lo mirare, muchas gracias

Comment: Curro! eres un Duro gracia, lo que comentaste funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: @EdwinAntury agregué un ejemplo que puede servirte, es el que se muestra en la imagen, saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Prueba esto:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> direccion;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

direccion = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // 1 representa la cantidad de resultados a obtener

String address = direccion.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = direccion.get(0).getLocality();
String state = direccion.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = direccion.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = direccion.get(0).getPostalCode();
...
```

Espero que te solucione tu problema.